# Embedded fonts appear squashed in Adobe AIR Mobile apps

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air, adobe, textfield

I have successfully embedded fonts in my AS3 code.

However when I did this, any font that I embed and use in a text field, the text appears a bit squashed vertically.
You could tell the difference if you view fields with embedded fonts and the ones with non embedded fonts, together side-by-side.
Does any body know why this might be happening?

---

Additional details:
Here is the code for my text field:

```
var readingFormat = new TextFormat("_calibri", readingSize, 0x484848,
null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.JUSTIFY, 10, 10, 2, 0);

var tempField = new TextField();
tempField.embedFonts = true;
tempField.defaultTextFormat = readingFormat;
tempField.selectable = false;
tempField.wordWrap = true;
tempField.text = "";
tempField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
tempField.width = 480;
```

In a font class which I call at the start of the app:

```
[Embed(systemFont="Calibri",
   fontName = "_calibri",
   fontFamily = "_calibri",
   mimeType = "application/x-font-truetype",
   embedAsCFF = "false")]
   public static const Calibri:Class;
```

..then I call function to register font.

And here's the sample text

[image: Sample text.. If it is compared to normal Calibri font, it is squashed]

---

Comparing the two:
Top one is embedded, bottom one is not embedded

[image: comparing]

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the text being squashed as well as an example of the TextField/Label instantiation, TextFormat/CSS application to said field, and how you are embedding the font itself? Without these, we really have nothing to go on to try and help you here.

Comment: Hi @JoshJanusch, I have added the details. Sorry for the delayed reply. As you can see in the sample picture, the text is squashed (or weird in some other manner)

Comment: Only thing that looks off is the line-height/leading which might be a bit small. Beyond that, I do not see any distortion or "squashing". Try increasing the leading and see if that helps at all.

Comment: @JoshJanusch Please see the last image in the post.

Comment: The only difference I see is anti-aliasing. Try setting `TextField.antiAliasType to `AntiAliasType.ADVANCED`.

Comment: @JoshJanusch I tried that but it actually makes no difference

Comment: Did you try setting it to NONE as well? The differences you are showing is anti-aliasing. You get little-to-no anti-aliasing on non-embedded fonts, so the bottom image is not anti-aliased at all.

Comment: @JoshJanusch there is no AntiAliasType.NONE, only normal or advanced.
Is there a way to change the character height/width manually?

Comment: Woops, my mistake. I meant normal. And no, there isn't. You can change line height, but that is it. It doesn't matter, though. As I have said, there is no difference in the width/height of the characters, only the AntiAliasing. I just opened that bottom image in Photoshop, used the marquee tool to outline 4 different characters and they were the same size in both sets of text.